# nested ajax request in angularjs and use $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

How can I use nested $http (ajax request in angularjs)?

```
$http({
    url:'/Project/getAllNotif',
    method:'POST'
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    angular.forEach(data, function(notif, key) {
        notif.msg = $sce.trustAsHtml(notif.msg);
    });
    $rootScope.notifs = data;
    if($rootScope.notifs.length != 0){
        angular.forEach($rootScope.notifs, function(notif, key) {
            ids.push(notif);
        });
    }
    $scope.ajaxCal2(ids);
});
```

I call a function in success of ajax request but it doesnt work and get me some errors like this

this is undefined

```
$scope.ajaxCall2= function(){

    $http({
                url:'/project/removeNotifs',
                method:'POST',
                data:$.param({'ids':$scope.ids}),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
               })
               .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                   $scope.notifNumber = 0;
                   console.log($scope.notifNumber);
       })


}
```

Comment: better share the detailed error message.

Comment: what function do you call in the success that gives you errors?

Comment: i edit my post and add calling function